# what is the role of gamma and epsilon in the calculation of K-L divergence?

Tags: machine-learning

I was wondering if anyone can explain to me why gamma and epsilon might be used to calculate the K-L divergence between two documents? What are their roles? I am not really good with maths so if someone can explain to me in simple terms that would be very helpful.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to the gamma and epsilon values defined in the paper [Using Kullback-Leibler Distance for Text Categorization](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/public/AD/Text%20Categorization/Using%20Kullback-Leibler%20Distance%20for%20Text%20Categorization.pdf).

`epsilon` is the probability of a term which is not in a document. It is set to a small value instead of 0 to avoid the distance to be infinite. `gamma` is a normalization coefficient to account of `epsilon`, so a probability of a term in a category satisfies the properties of a probability (sum to 1).

Comment: @Stanisals Hello, thank you for taking the time to answer my question! However I am still confused, I was wondering if you can give an example?

Comment: Please look at equation (5) page 6 until the end of the page of the linked paper. It gives you how the probabilities are computed. The ``epsilon`` is here to avoid infinity in equation (3). And ``gamma`` is here because of ``epsilon`` (otherwise it will be 1).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't epsilon be used to avoid a term being "undefined", rather than infinite? Anything divided by zero is, afterall, undefined.